# How do I query a PostgreSQL JSON column for a specific type of value?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table `responses` which has a JSON column `value`. The `value` column *should* be an array of text values, like so:

```
["Value One", "Value Two", "Value Three"]
```

However, a bug in the associated application resulted in some of these values being saved as a string, like:

```
"Value One"
```

Is there a way to query this column for only text/string types so I can address the bad entries?

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [`jsonb_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), e.g.:

```
with responses(value) as (
values
    ('["Value One", "Value Two", "Value Three"]'::jsonb),
    ('"Value One"')
)

select *
from responses
where jsonb_typeof(value) <> 'array'

    value    
-------------
 "Value One"
(1 row)
```